# Exclude word from redirect with Regex in NGINX

Tags: regex, nginx

I am trying to match anything the user could input but a single word. This will match anything but the word, but variable $1 is empty.

```
rewrite ^/folder/((?:(?!word).)*)/$ /folder/$1/;
rewrite ^/folder/((?:(?!word).)*)/$ /folder/index.php?i=$1;
```

Example:

www.example.com/folder/a will just rewrite to www.example.com/folder/a//
And also redirects to //
www.example.com/folder/a/ will just rewrite to www.example.com/folder/a//

I feel like I am very close to the solution, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the first capturing group is quantified, and the `.` is re-captured 0 or more times, with the last char captured with `.` in Group 1 (`$1`) at the end.

You need to re-write the tempered greedy token with a non-capturing group and wrap it with a capturing one:

```
rewrite ^/folder/((?:(?!word).)*)/$ /folder/$1/;
                 ^^^^           ^
```

Now, the `(?:(?!word).)*` construct uses a non-capturing group (no redundant group re-assignment is involved) and the outer `(...)` form a capturing group with ID 1.

Comment: I added the second set of brackets, I did not those before, it seems to work now, but, it's adding a slash after the word.  I've never had it do that to the variable before.

Comment: Then remove the final slash in the replacement - `/folder/$1;`

Comment: rewrite ^/folder/((?:(?!word).)*)/$ /folder/index.php?i=$1;